# Select one product at a time

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am crawling the following site using selenium in python

[Snapdeal website](http://www.snapdeal.com/products/health-nutrition?q=Brand:BSN%5E%20Domin8r%5E%20ON%5E%20SSN%5E%20Ultimate%20nutrition%7C&#bstslr%7CBrand:BSN%5E%20ON%7CGender_s:Men%7C)

I could either download only the first link using `find_element_by_xpath()` or all at once using `find_elements_by_xpath()`.

I want to select each object one by one, get its price and then get second product and then its second price and so on.

Isn't there any other method to crawl so that I'll get the desired results?

Comment: Use the `find_elements_by_xpath()` as you are, this returns a list. Then iterate over the list to do an action for each item within the list.